# Google map on iphone apps : current location

Tags: iphone, mkmapview, mkannotation

I am working on an iPhone app in which I am implementing a map view. When the map loads, a purple pin is displayed at the current location. My problem is that I want to show the current location on a new view when the user touches this purple pin.

Any idea?

Please help.

Thanks,
Aaryan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a user taps an annotation pin, callout annotation and accessory views can be displayed. The callout accessory views can be controls (buttons) with associated actions.

If callout views will not meet your needs, you could instead put invisible buttons with your own actions over the pins on the map view.

In either case, you can display views, navigate, etc in the method(s) called by the button actions.